# NodeJS - Require module

Tags: node.js, module, require

I have 3 own modules(X,Y,Z). When app starts I require X, then X require Y, next Y require Z, but Z need Y - so i require Z in Y and i see only empty object. Any ideas how to fix it ?

```
console.log(require('./../Y'))  //in Z - returns {}
```

Comment: What parts of `Z` do you need to use in `Y` and vice-versa? Export them first. (Better: don’t have circular dependencies if possible.)

Comment: Ok it works - i use exports (no module.exports) and it works. Thanks.